# How to import .csv file in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing an issue with importing excel table in `mySQL`. I have 2 columns where one is ID and the other one is names. I've saved the excel file as `.csv` and created 2 columns but each time I import the `.csv` file it is putting the data under one column. Can you please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: user `\t` for new tab while printing new column or show your code

Comment: I am using the import option in phpMyAdmin within the database I've created

Comment: actually I've solved it, realized that the steps given in the net differs with couple of steps